# JQuery: Read selected razor(@item.Id) from foreach.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I list all products via foreach. I'm trying to show my selected `product.Id` via Alert by clicking on the button that were created from foreach. But I don't know how to proceed. How do I allow alert to read the specific `item.ID` that were selected/clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.add-to-cart').click(function () {
            alert(item.ID);  //something like this        
        });
    });

</script>
```

-

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

/*@item.ID*/

   <button class="add-to-cart">Add to Cart</button>

  }    
}
```

Comment: Add the `ID` as a `data-*` attribute - `<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="@item.ID">Add to Cart</button>` and get it using `alert($(this).data('id'));`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onclick() function like this:

```
   <button class="add-to-cart" onclick = "AddToCart('@item.Id')">Add to Cart</button>
```

in your script,

```
<script>
    function AddToCart(id)
    {
          alert(id);
    }
    </script>
```

OR

you can use data-* attribute to button,

```
<button class="add-to-cart" data-ID="@item.ID">Add to Cart</button>
```

in your script,

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add-to-cart').click(function () {
              alert($(this).data('ID'));    
            });
        });
 </script>
```